# PHP retrieve POST result

Tags: php, authentication, oauth, request, http-post

I'm trying to create an App for 'Exact Online' but i'm having a little bit of a problem with the OAuth security authentication

https://developers.exactonline.com/#OAuth_Tutorial.html%3FTocPath%3DAuthentication%7C_____2

After making my first authentication request and logging in I recieve a code.
With this code I can obtain an Token for making api calls.

```
if (!empty($_GET["code"])){
$code = $_GET["code"];
```

getting the code works so far. But when I try to make a new request (for the token) I get no response data.
My Code is as follows:

```
$data = array(
    'code' => $code,
    'redirect_uri' => 'http://****/asdf2.php',
    'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
    'client_id' => '******-****-****-******-*****',
    'client_secret' => '*********'
);
// Create map with request parameters

// Build Http query using params
$query = http_build_query ($data);

// Create Http context details
$contextData = array ( 
                'method' => 'POST',
                'header' => "Connection: close\r\n".
                            "Content-Length: ".strlen($query)."\r\n",
                'content'=> $query );

// Create context resource for our request
$context = stream_context_create (array ( 'http' => $contextData ));

    // Read page rendered as result of your POST request
$result =  file_get_contents (
                  'https://start.exactonline.nl/api/oauth2/token',  // page url
                  false,
                  $context);

// Server response is now stored in $result variable so you can process it
if (!empty($result)){
echo "success"; 
}else{
echo "no result";
}
}else { 
echo "error";
}
```

$result is always empty, what could be the problem. I've checked my client_id and secret multiple times.

After changing it to cUrl it still didn't work:

```
$result = get_oauth2_token($code); 

// Server response is now stored in $result variable so you can process it
if (!empty($result)){
echo "success";
}else{
echo "no result";
}
}else { 
echo "error";
}

/*
Function
*/

function get_oauth2_token($code) {

global $client_id;
global $client_secret;
global $redirect_uri;

$oauth2token_url = "https://start.exactonline.nl/api/oauth2/token";
$clienttoken_post = array(
    'code' => $code,
    'redirect_uri' => 'http://*****/asdf2.php',
    'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
    'client_id' => '{*******}',
    'client_secret' => '******'
);

$curl = curl_init($oauth2token_url);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $clienttoken_post);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$json_response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

$authObj = json_decode($json_response);

if (isset($authObj->refresh_token)){
    //refresh token only granted on first authorization for offline access
    //save to db for future use (db saving not included in example)
    global $refreshToken;
    $refreshToken = $authObj->refresh_token;
}

$accessToken = $authObj->access_token;
return $accessToken;
}
```

Comment: Maybe use `cURL` instead?

Comment: Already tried it, but didn't work either... I'll try again and post an update ;)

Comment: I didn't have CURL installed.. now it works :)

Answer (score 0):

The documentation shows that `client_id` should be inside curly braces. So I think it should be:

```
'client_id' => '{******-****-****-******-*****}',
```

Comment: nope, didn't make a difference... But thanks for the heads-up :)

Comment: Is it returning an empty response or `false`?

Comment: At this point im getting an Status Code:500 Internal Server Error from Exact Online.. so that isn't helping either :(.  Added cURL code to the project

Comment: Either there's a problem with the API, or you're not sending the correct parameters.

Comment: Oke, thanks! I'll contact Exact Online for a solution and post it back here later today